# Unable to run the parametrized batch file on remote machine using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, remote-server, parameterized

Execute the remote server parametrized batch file from PowerShell.

Doesn't throw an error nor executed command on remote machine.

```
$path = "D:\run\test-5.2.bat";
Invoke-Command -ComputerName testserver -Scriptblock { "$path" }
```

Script inside the bat file is `msiexec` with parameters, which shall execute through Command Prompt only.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1), you can run a `ps1` script file on remote computers. So if it is possible to "port" the content of the `bat` file in a `ps1` it should work. Here is the msdn example:

> Example 11: Run a script on all the computers listed in a text file

```
 PS C:\> Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content Servers.txt) -FilePath C:\Scripts\Sample.ps1 -ArgumentList Process, Service
```

> This example uses the Invoke-Command cmdlet to run the Sample.ps1 script on all of the computers listed in the Servers.txt file. The command uses the FilePath parameter to specify the script file. This command lets you run the script on the remote computers, even if the script file is not accessible to the remote computers.
>
> When you submit the command, the content of the Sample.ps1 file is copied into a script block and the script block is run on each of the remote computers. This procedure is equivalent to using the ScriptBlock parameter to submit the contents of the script.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your response, My script inside the bat file works only from Command line and rest of my automation script written in PowerShell, so i cannot change bat to .ps1, my bat file is already copied on target machine and paramaterized with build number

Comment: Add the content of the bat file to the description

Answer (score 0):

`$path` is a string. PowerShell simply echoes bare strings instead of executing them, unlike CMD or bash. Use the call operator (`&`):

```
& "$path"
```

or `Start-Process`:

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c', $path -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

to have PowerShell execute a string as a command. Since you say you're running `msiexec.exe` from the batch script using the latter may be required.

On top of that you have a scope issue. The variable `$path` inside the scriptblock is not the same as the one in the global scope. You can mitigate that via the `using:` scope qualifier:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer testserver -Scriptblock { & "$using:path" }
```

or by passing `$path` as an argument to the scriptblock:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer testserver -Scriptblock { & "$($args[0])" } -ArgumentList $path
```

Comment: Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c', $path -NoNewWindow -Wait
this is executing but not installing the application.

Comment: tried all three, but even not throwing any errors when i execute with the above format

Comment: My answer describes how to run a command on a remote host. For further troubleshooting you need to show your batch script and maybe also installer logs.